# StructureMap Registration Order

Tags: c#, structuremap

Using StructureMap 2.6.4.

I have seen several references on SO and elsewhere that registering a service twice will result in the last registered implementation "winning" as the default.

From my tests, using WhatDoIHave, it seems to be the opposite.  If I do:

```
For<IMyService>().Singleton().Use<MyService>();
For<IMyService>().Use<MyService>();
```

It appears that my service remains registered as a singleton.

My real question revolves around Scanning and Autoregistration.  I need a few specific services registered as singletons, and want to register the rest of my services via convention (transient).  So should I do explicit registrations first or last?

```
For<IMyService>().Singleton().Use<MyService>();

Scan(
    scan =>
    {
        scan.WithDefaultConventions();
        scan.TheCallingAssembly();
    });
```

If possible please cite the documentation, as the answer I see posted seems to conflict with my (possibly flawed) testing.